# fink-0.44.0をインストールしようとしたらbzip2-1.0.6.tar.gzがインストールできず終わらなかった。

Tags: macos, unix

環境はMac OS X(ver 10.12.5)です。
apt-getをインストールしたくてfinkのインストールを試みましたが
bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz がインストールできないため途中でgive upしてしまいました

[image: 以下が示されたerrorの全容です。]

Answer (score 1):

指定したURLにファイルが存在しないのが原因です。

該当のURLをブラウザで開くとトップページにリダイレクトされるので、実行された環境ではHTMLファイルがダウンロードされてしまいハッシュのチェックでエラーになっているのでしょう。

http://www.bzip.org/downloads.html には「最新版はSourceForgeから探して」とあります。

質問に貼られたスクリーンショットには映っていませんが、何かバッチファイル等で実行されているのでしょうか。
手動でダウンロードする場合には、以下の手順で正常なファイルの保存、ハッシュ値の確認(expected=期待値との一致)をすることができました。
私が試したのはWindowsのGit Bash環境で、あくまでbzip2のダウンロードだけです。

```
$ curl -o bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz -L https://sourceforge.net/projects/bzip2/files/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz/download
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 16367  100 16367    0     0  22890      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 22890
100   313  100   313    0     0    230      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   690
100  763k  100  763k    0     0   454k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  454k

$ file bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz
bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, was "bzip2-1.0.6.tar", last modified: Mon Sep 20 07:15:13 2010, from Unix, original size 2590720

$ md5sum bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz
00b516f4704d4a7cb50a1d97e6e8e15b *bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz
```